# How do I install Intellij on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I keep receiving this error:

```
miguel@Miguel:~$ cd '/home/miguel/Downloads/idea-IU-141.1010.3/bin' 
miguel@Miguel:~/Downloads/idea-IU-141.1010.3/bin$ ./idea.sh
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: maybe `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` ? http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_IntelliJ_IDEA_on_Ubuntu

Comment: Does `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` mean from an environment variable? You might have a different JVM with a different options format. You could remove or override that environment variable in idea.sh or another shell script to call it or whatever settings it loads.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
first I erased the "-XX:MaxPermSize=350m" inside the idea64.vmoptions file, then I pointed the JAVA_HOME with the next command:

```
~$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```